# pythonanywhere making scrrenshot in browser

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, pythonanywhere

i am trying to make screenshot from browser by using selenium in pythonanywhere 
this is my code :

```
    display = Display(visible=0, size=(800, 600))
    display.start()

    browser = webdriver.Firefox()
    print(4)
    browser.implicitly_wait(15)
    url='http://whattomine.com/coins?utf8=%E2%9C%93&adapt_q_280x=290&adapt_q_380=0&adapt_q_fury=0&adapt_q_470=0&adapt_q_480=3&adapt_q_570=0&adapt_q_580=0&adapt_q_750Ti=0&adapt_q_10606=0&adapt_q_1070=0&adapt_q_1080=0&adapt_q_1080Ti=0&eth=true&factor%5Beth_hr%5D=0.0&factor%5Beth_p%5D=0.0&factor%5Bgro_hr%5D=0.0&factor%5Bgro_p%5D=0.0&factor%5Bx11g_hr%5D=0.0&factor%5Bx11g_p%5D=0.0&factor%5Bcn_hr%5D=0.0&factor%5Bcn_p%5D=0.0&factor%5Beq_hr%5D=0.0&factor%5Beq_p%5D=0.0&factor%5Blrev2_hr%5D=0.0&factor%5Blrev2_p%5D=0.0&factor%5Bns_hr%5D=0.0&factor%5Bns_p%5D=0.0&factor%5Blbry_hr%5D=0.0&factor%5Blbry_p%5D=0.0&factor%5Bbk2b_hr%5D=0.0&factor%5Bbk2b_p%5D=0.0&factor%5Bbk14_hr%5D=0.0&factor%5Bbk14_p%5D=0.0&factor%5Bpas_hr%5D=0.0&factor%5Bpas_p%5D=0.0&factor%5Bskh_hr%5D=0.0&factor%5Bskh_p%5D=0.0&factor%5Bl2z_hr%5D=420.0&factor%5Bl2z_p%5D=300.0&factor%5Bcost%5D=0.1&sort=Profitability24&volume=0&revenue=24h&factor%5Bexchanges%5D%5B%5D=&factor%5Bexchanges%5D%5B%5D=bittrex&factor%5Bexchanges%5D%5B%5D=bleutrade&factor%5Bexchanges%5D%5B%5D=bter&factor%5Bexchanges%5D%5B%5D=c_cex&factor%5Bexchanges%5D%5B%5D=cryptopia&factor%5Bexchanges%5D%5B%5D=hitbtc&factor%5Bexchanges%5D%5B%5D=poloniex&factor%5Bexchanges%5D%5B%5D=yobit&dataset=Main&commit=Calculate'
    print(url)
    browser.get(url)
    browser.implicitly_wait(15)
    print(3)
    browser.save_screenshot('/home/arator/1test.png')
    browser.quit()
    img = Image.open('/home/arator/1test.png')
    width, height = img.size

    crop_rectangle = ( 10 ,1060, 1150, 1645 )
    cropped_img = img.crop(crop_rectangle)

    cropped_img.save('/home/arator/12test.png')
    w2=open('/home/arator/12test.png','rb')
```

it works fine first time , but after i got the following error:

```
http.client.RemoteDisconnected: Remote end closed connection without response
```

how to fix this problem?
If its imposible to fix this problem on pythonanywhere maybe there is some other way to make screenshot from browser

Comment: did you try debugging your code?

Comment: You're not cleaning up your display or your browser when you're done. Look at the PythonAnywhere docs for why you should and how to do it.